# Unable to install using the terminal apt-get install command?

Tags: apt, gnome-terminal

I had installed Scala a day before, everything was working well, but after that whenever I want to install any other app using the apt-get install command it starts to give the strange problems. The output for the problem I have faced is given below while installing the nodejs.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to launch the command `sudo apt-get install -f`? And if it still fails, please provide its output.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting.

Comment: Like the machine suggested.. try this `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f`